# How to prevent static variable became null after application holds for long time

Tags: sqlite, static, android

I have developed and released one application in market long ago. Now some some users pointed crashes when holding application for long time. Now I identified the reason for the crash, that is I am using a class with static variable and methods to store data (getters and setters). Now I want to replace the static way with any other ways.From my study I got the following suggestions:

1. shared preferences: I have to store more than 40 variable (strings, int and json arrays and objects), So I think using shared preferences is not a good idea.
2. SQLite: more than 40 fields are there and I don't need to keep more than one value at a time.I am getting values for fields from different activities. I mean name from one activity , age from another activity, etc So using SQLite also not a good Idea I think.
3. Application classes: Now I am thinking about using application classes to store these data. Will it loss the data like static variable after hold the app for long time?

   - Now I replace the static variable with application class . Please let me know that application data also became null after long time?

It may useful to somebody.

Even though I didn't get a solution for my problem, I got the reason for why shouldn't we use application objects to hold the data. Please check the below link

[Don't use application object to store data](http://www.developerphil.com/dont-store-data-in-the-application-object/)

Comment: `So I think using shared preferences is not a good idea.` why??

Comment: SO many downvotes, please give me an answer. If you think it is sub standared question, then I am ready to remove after I get a solution.

Comment: `SharedPreferences` is the easiest solution for you. I don't know why do you think it as `not a good idea`..!!

Comment: +1 I am facing a similar issue in the app another developer started and I am maintaining.

Comment: @Aniruddha..I have to store more than 40 fields and some values are jsonArray and JsonObjects...Is it possible to store those values in SharedPreference?

Comment: If you have data in JSON format, then you can just save it to a `File` and parse it whenever you need to reload the data.

Answer (score 1):

Normally if you have to keep something in case your Activity gets destroyed you save all these things in `onSaveInstanceState` and restore them in `onCreate` or in `onRestoreInstanceState`

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

int myVariable;
final String ARG_MY_VAR="myvar";

public void onCreate(Bundle savedState) {
if(savedState != null {
   myVariable = savedState.getInt(ARG_MY_VAR);
} else {
   myVariable = someDefaultValue;
}

public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putInt(ARG_MY_VAR, myVariable);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

}
}
```

Here if Android OS destroys your Activity `onSaveInstanceState` will be called and your important variable will be saved. Then when the user returns to your app again Android OS restores the activity and your variable will be correctly initialized

This does not happen when you call `finish()` yourself though, it happens only when Android destroys your activity for some reasons (which is quite likely to happen anytime while your app is in background).

Comment: Please give me a detailed description..thanks for the answer.

Comment: I am facing similar issue the previous developer had static arraylist bitmaps and other pojo classes. When the app comes from background because the variables are not there anymore app crashes. Is there a quick fix for this problem?

Comment: @Illegal Argument for a plain class  you could use singleton model static MyClass getInstance() { if(instance == null) { instance = new MyClass(); } return instance; }.  this way it always gets inited as needed. you may have to add some synchronization as they show in the books

Comment: @Alex ...Thanks a lot, I have to store jsonArrays and objects some times..We can't store those values in bundle..right?

Comment: Surely Bundle does not have an API like putJsonArray. However, you could put whatever you need by using those APIs Bundle does have. You can also make your class serializable and use Bundle.putSerializable although that could easily lead to problems. Still maybe you just can save your jsons in a sharedpreference after all

Comment: @Alex..what is your option about using Application class to store..Adding getters and setters in to application class?..will it also loss data  like static?

Comment: @sarath Surely, the data will be lost unless you specifically save them at a right point of your program. When Android OS recreates your App object it won't by itself know about the values of the static variables which were there before.

Comment: @Alex..So your option is using onSaveInstanceState and onCreate() ..right?..But when we open application from recent application, the activity won't go to onCreate() ..isn't it?.. oncreate or onRestoreInstanceState  ..which is the best way?

Answer (score 0):

First you should overwrite the onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState methods in you activity:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState){
    outState.putString("myVariable", myVariable);
    // Store all you data inside the bundle
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState (Bundle savedInstanceState){
    if(savedInstanceState != null){
        myVariable = savedInstanceState.getString("myVariable");
        // Restore all the variables
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be try use static variable inside Application space?

```
public class YourApplication extends Application
 {
   private static ApplicationBubblick singleton;
   public  String str;

   public static YourApplication getInstance()
    {
      return singleton;
    }
 }
```

And use variable via:

```
YourApplication.getInstance().str = ...; // set variable

... = YourApplication.getInstance().str; // get variable
```

This variable will be live until your app will start and stop all services or activities of your app. This is not work when your app crash.

Comment: we should we use static variable inside the application class?

Comment: Dont save data in application object.http://www.developerphil.com/dont-store-data-in-the-application-object/

Comment: Yes, I know that. Variables in app object lives to app died (kill by OS after sleep many time, crash etc.). This is work for "fast" case. Right way - SharedPreferences, but this is not best solution for permanent saving biges data. You also can protect your app from OS killing by run Sticky Service or create every-minute BroadcastReceiver or similar things...